# Python Twitter Json

Tags: python, json, twitter

I've a json file, which I got from twitter. How to parse the following to json?

```
{"min_position":"456662757081759744","has_more_items":true,"items_html":"\n      \u003cli class=\"js-stream-item stream-item stream-item expanding-stream-item\n\" data-item-id=\"469180261804941313\" id=\"stream-item-tweet-469180261804941313\" data-item-type=\"tweet\"\u003e\n      \n\n\n  \n\n  \u003cdiv class=\"tweet original-tweet js-original-tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n has-cards\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\"\n    \ndata-tweet-id=\"469180261804941313\"\n\ndata-disclosure-type=\"\"\ndata-item-id=\"469180261804941313\"\ndata-permalink-path=\"\/Modi\/status\/469180261804941313\"\n\n\n data-screen-name=\"Modi\" data-name=\"narendra modi\" data-user-id=\"180470326\"\n\n\n data-has-cards=\"true\"\n\n\ndata-card2-type=\"summary_large_image\"\n\n\n\n\ndata-expanded-footer=\"&lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-details-fixer tweet-details-fixer&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;card2 js-media-container&quot; data-card2-name=&quot;summary_large_image&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-macaw-cards-iframe-container&quot;&#10;  data-src=&quot;\/i\/cards\/tfw\/v1\/469180261804941313?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&amp;amp;lang=en&quot;&#10;  data-autoplay-src=&quot;\/i\/cards\/tfw\/v1\/469180261804941313?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&amp;amp;lang=en&quot;&#10;  data-card-name=&quot;summary_large_image&quot;&#10;  data-card-url=&quot;http:\/\/t.co\/65EbIXxYok&quot;&#10;  data-publisher-id=&quot;134758540&quot;&#10;  data-creator-id=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-amplify-content-id=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-amplify-playlist-url=&quot;&quot;&#10;  data-full-card-iframe-url=&quot;\/i\/cards\/tfw\/v1\/469180261804941313?cardname=summary_large_image&amp;amp;earned=true&amp;amp;lang=en&quot;&#10;  data-has-autoplayable-media=&quot;false&quot;&gt;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;js-machine-translated-tweet-container&quot;&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;    &lt;div class=&quot;js-tweet-stats-container tweet-stats-container &quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;  &lt;div class=&quot;client-and-actions&quot;&gt;&#10;  &lt;span class=&quot;metadata&quot;&gt;&#10;    &lt;span&gt;11:17 AM - 21 May 2014&lt;\/span&gt;&#10;       &amp;middot; &lt;a class=&quot;permalink-link js-permalink js-nav&quot; href=&quot;\/Modi\/status\/469180261804941313&quot;  tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;Details&lt;\/a&gt;&#10;  &lt;\/span&gt;&#10;&lt;\/div&gt;&#10;&#10;&#10;&lt;","new_latent_count":18}
```

Note :Removed lot of data for limited character error.

Comment: So you are asking how to parse JSON to JSON?

Comment: Which library are you using to contact the Twitter API?

Comment: @timgeb I've loaded like `json_data = json.load(datajson)` and printed min_position value as `print json_data['min_position']` but if need to print something from "items_html" nothing is happening.

Comment: @pzp I'm not using any API. Testing my best with https

Comment: @jOSe What is the https request you are making then?

Comment: @pzp I'm requesting for old tweet. And trying to filter out time, or url links in it.

Comment: @jOSe you should include all the relevant information in your question. most of us are not clairvoyant.

Comment: @timgeb Okay. Thanks

Comment: You can parse JSON with the json package and json.loads(mydatastring) if you want to read a string. If you have any problems with this, you should post your  errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: @Randrian You can see value like \u003 and more like that are making problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is small example for parsing JSON from geocode.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

response = urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=new+york&sensor=false')

# don't forget to encode response 
data = str(response.read(), encoding='utf-8') # python 3
# data = str(response.read()) # python 2

print(data)

# use json.loads 
my_dict = json.loads(data)

print(my_dict)
print(my_dict['status'])
```

Print data outpit:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            ...
```

Created dict:

```
{'status': 'OK', 'results': [{'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'place_id': 'ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g', 'formatted_address': 'New York, NY, USA', 'address_components': [{'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'NY',
```

And status:

```
print(my_dict['status'])
>>> OK
```

Comment: Added replacement for python 2, related to str() error

Comment: I used 2.7. What is the future 3 or 2.7?

Comment: Now used both, but also exists good doc about versions: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3